# debug "ajax request" with debugkit cakephp plugin on google chrome

Tags: ajax, debugging, google-chrome, cakephp

i'm using "[debugkit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit)" (awesome **cakephp** plugin) to debug my "Sql request, view Vars, session vars ...) but this plugin doesn't **debug** "**the AJAX request**" :(

so i have always to use the **Google Chrome** "**Network XHR** section" and it's not very "**useful**"

is there a solution to debug "the AJAX request" directly on the "debugKit cakehp plugin" ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Debug Kit is great, but for what you're looking for, it will not work.  You're much better off using something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  This will give you the ability to inspect your ajax requests in real time, and it is significantly more robust than the inspector in Chrome.

There is a Firebug version available for Chrome (Firebug Lite), but the Firefox version is much better and I'd highly recommend you at least try it out.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP DebugKit is compatible with [FirePHP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firephp/), a Firebug extension that copies the same debugging info DebugKit shows on the pages, into Firebug console.

Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

here how to do it

Simply choose the `History` tab and click on the ajax request to need to inspect the data. It will load the necessary data and you can open tabs and see the info as if it would be a non-ajax request.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/2015/04/26/queries_log_for_your_ajax_requests.html